# Position advantage on the table and odds

Tags: poker-theory, betting-position

Is it possible define position advantage on table on terms of correction to odds? Namely,  is it possible to quantify the effect of position on a players equity?

Comment: Clarify, please.

Comment: I think the question asks if its possible to quantify the effect of position on a players equity?!

Comment: @TobyBooth If that's true, then this is a great question :) .

Comment: you right Toby Booth. Thanx, my english is not so good :)

Comment: Intuitively, I think it's obvious that being In-Position has a positive effect on how often a player wins a hand, thus a positive effect on equity. I'd also say that it would be incredibly difficult to quantify. It would be good to know though :)

Comment: http://phys.org/news/2015-01-em-heads-up-limit-poker.html in this article it is stated that position give you an extra 0.088 blinds. I don't know how to translate it in playable hands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [chart](http://www.tightpoker.com/hands/ev_position.html) shows how position effects expected value, which is what I think you are interested in from reading your question.

Comment: People should note, and you should maybe edit your question to reflect this, that this table is only a table of expected value froma sample of hands it is not an absolute calculation

Answer (score 3):

Position has no effect on odds, which are determined by relative hand strength and is the same regardless of position.

Theoretically speaking, equity is impacted by position but it would be impossible to define as it would be different for every player, and also different for every player against every opponent and further still different for every player against every opponent with every possible hand combination. The only way to know for sure what the true equity would be for each of those would be to have a massive sample size of hands for all possibilities, which could never happen.

If you are seeking to define it in general terms for all players, I suggest you just toss the idea. If you are seeking to define it for one player and you have access to a very large sample of hands for that one player, then you may be able to accomplish something.

Say you have a huge sample of hands for this one player playing 6-max NLHE at low stakes, on the same online poker site, where we can assume the competition is relatively similar, on average, over the entire sample. All you would need to do is examine the expected value of each hand and how it varies by position. For example: how much was won or lost, on average, with AA from UTG, UTG+1, UTG+2, Button, SB and BB. You now know how the equity of having AA varies by position. Do that for every hand combination.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the later your position, the greater the probability that you have the best hand.

Not sure what you mean by equity though.

But in terms of probability:

Suppose the probability that a random hand is better than yours is p.

if you have one player to act, the probability that you have the best had is 1-p.

if you have n players to act, that probability is approximately (1-p)^n.

Comment: But, can you define it quantitatively?

Comment: yes, i will try to do some editing.

Comment: see edited post

Comment: Being in later position doesn't increase the probability that you have a good hand. The advantage from being in position comes from having the most information when it is your turn to act, and the fact that your opponents have less information when they act ( they don't know what your action will be ).

Answer (score -3):

Late position is advantageous only against passive players. Late position is vulnerable to bluffing by earlier players. Position is actually not that great advantage as thought by many. If a player go all in at UTG with any hand his probability of winning is greater than 1/no of players,since some of them in later position will definitely fold. But for the dealer the probability of winning is less than 1/no of players in the game, since some of those betting heavily will have a better hand than what you have.

Comment: Having an aggressive player act before me is hugely advantageous, but you dont seem to think that. Why?